# Treeview with multiple (two) hierarchical child nodes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to build a tree structure which consists of a root element and contains 2 child elements. The child elements in turn contain other children.

The elements below the root are separate classes, which have nothing to do with each other.

Now I have problems with the display in WPF I can not manage to display both elements under the root correctly

The whole thing should look like this:

```
Configuration 1
 - Zones
    - Zone 1
    - Zone 2
 - Probes
    - Probe 1
    - Probe 2

Configuration 2
 - Zones
    - Zone 1
    - Zone 2
 - Probes
    - Probe 1
    - Probe 2
```

This is my markup:

```
     <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}">

        <TreeView.Resources>
           <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key ="ZoneTemplate" DataType="{x:Type common:VMZonesPlan}" ItemsSource="{Binding ZonePlans}">
              <TextBlock Text="Zone XY"/>
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type common:VMZone}">
                    <ui:EditableTextBlock  Text="{Binding ZoneName}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

           <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ZoneHeader" DataType="{x:Type vm:VMZones}" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Zones}" 
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ZoneTemplate}">

              <TextBlock x:Uid="TitleText"  Text="ZoneTitle"/>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>


           <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key ="ProbeTemplate" DataType="{x:Type vm:VMProbeEndeffectors}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProbeEndeffectors}">
              <TextBlock Text="Zone XY"/>
              <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="Probe Child"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
              </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

           <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="ProbeHeader" DataType="{x:Type vm:VMProbe}" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Probes}" 
                                     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProbeTemplate}">

              <TextBlock x:Uid="TitleText"  Text="ZoneTitle"/>
           </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
     </TreeView>
```

and this is my code:

```
public class VMTreeView: ViewModelBase 
{
     public ObservableCollection <ViewModelConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }

     public VMTreeView() 
     {
         Configurations = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelConfiguration>();
         var firstNode = new Configuration(param);
         Configurations.Add(firstNode);
     }
}

public class ViewModelConfiguration 
{
     public ObservableCollection<Probe> Probes { get; set; }
     public ObservableCollection<Zones> Zones { get; set; }

     public ViewModelConfiguration() 
     {
         Probes = new ObservableCollection <Probe> {...};
         Zones = new ObservableCollection <Zones> {...};
     }
}
```

I have already seen that it is possible somehow what do I have to change? or can WPF not so?

Comment: Your sample code is a mess. What is `DMEConfigurations` and `Configuration`?

Comment: thanks for the tip, copy paste error this is a very complex example i have simplified for here

Answer (score 0):

You should define an hierarchical type that contains children of itself:

```
public class ViewModelConfiguration
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelConfiguration> Children { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelConfiguration>();

    public ViewModelConfiguration(string name) =>
        Name = name;

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Configurations}">

    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModelConfiguration}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

You then build the tree of probes and zones in your view model:

```
public class VMTreeView
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelConfiguration> Configurations { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelConfiguration>();

    public VMTreeView()
    {
        var conf1 = new ViewModelConfiguration("Conf. 1");
        var zones = new ViewModelConfiguration("Zones");
        var zone1 = new ViewModelConfiguration("Zone 1");
        var zone2 = new ViewModelConfiguration("Zone 2");
        zones.Children.Add(zone1);
        zones.Children.Add(zone2);
        conf1.Children.Add(zones);

        Configurations.Add(conf1);
        ...
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: and where are the probes? are they missing in your example? 
that is exactly my problem. Zones and children are on the same level and are already present as children in the configuration. a hirachical template where only zones or children bind is no problem. It only becomes problematic when I want to bind both of them

Comment: The probles is just another `ViewModelConfiguration` being added to `conf1`. I thought that was obvious, sorry. You don't bind to both of them. You bind to a single property and then build the tree yourself in the view model as I wrote in the answer.